# Grab HTML that a jQuery plugin generates

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, widget

I have a plugin from a supplier, which i can only include in my website like this:

```
<p>my content</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgeturl"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    showWidget();
</script>
<!--widget inserts lots of HTML here -->

<p>more of my content</p>
```

Now, the HTML that this script generates is pretty ugly and i would like to attach an event handler to some event that notifies me when the widget script has done it's work and i can start grabbing/modifying the HTML that it has generated.

Can anyone explain how i would do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `showWidget()` is blocking (which it seems to be since it's inserting HTML directly after its own script), you can just put another `<script>` tag underneath it and do stuff with the HTML preceding it.